# Symfony2 Choice : Expected argument of type "scalar", "array" given

Tags: forms, security, symfony

I'm making a form with a choice list. Here's the content of my FormType (only as a test):

```
$builder->add('regionUser');
$builder->add('roles' ,'choice' ,array('choices' => array(
        "ROLE_ADMIN" => "ROLE_ADMIN",
            "ROLE_USER" => "ROLE_USER",
        ),
        'required'  => true,
        'multiple' => false,
));
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

> Expected argument of type "scalar", "array" given

What goes wrong? How to solve it?

Comment: Is this form "binded" to an object (i suppose yes) so, can you insert the whole code of the class object binded to it?

Comment: I'm using FOSUserBundle, and `roles` is an attribute of FOSUser, but it's probably waiting for an array (given that the database entry is a serialized array). But the problem is that `choices` indexes (the actual values) cannot be arrays.

Comment: I don't think that `choices` cannot be arrays. Take a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) so i ask you, are you sure that into `FOSUser` you expected a roleas an array ?

Comment: As I said, the database entry is an array, and the choices doesn't accept a simple string (as you can see in the original post). If a string was expected, what would be wrong in my code?

Comment: Without more code i suppose that isn't easy to help you

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php 
Here's the code for the User class

Comment: mh ok, but i suppose that the error has to be "away" from here... I don't notice nothing strange in that snippet of code

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 3 solutions:

1. Use a multiple choices field to show the roles field. Multiple 
   choices returns a array.
2. In your form, don't show the "roles" field. 
   Put a new field "role" only in your buildform, not in your entity. 
   (You can fill autmaticaly it with the role hierarchy if you want). 
   In the onSuccess method, get the "role" to set roles for your user.

> $user->addRole( $role );

1. When you create your user class, don't use the UserInterface from 
   the FOSUserBundle. Copy it and change the prototype of the method.

> // FOSUserBundle/UserInterface
>
> function setRoles(array $roles);
>
> ```
> // YourUserBundle/UserInterface 
> function setRoles($roles);
> ```
>
> And change the method in your User Class
>
> ```
> // FOSUserBundle/UserInterface 
> public function setRoles(array $roles) 
> { 
>         $this->roles = array(); 
>         foreach ($roles as $role) { 
>             $this->addRole($role); 
>         } 
> } 
>
> // YourUserBundle/UserInterface 
> public function setRoles($roles) 
> { 
>         if (is_string()) { 
>             $this->addRole($roles); 
>         } else { 
>             $this->roles = array(); 
>             foreach ($roles as $role) { 
>                 $this->addRole($role); 
>             } 
>         } 
> }
> ```

You can find more information here: https://groups.google.com/group/symfony2/browse_thread/thread/3dd0d26bcaae4f82/4e091567abe764f9

http://blog.aelius.fr/blog/2011/11/allow-user-to-choose-role-at-registration-in-symfony2-fosuserbundle-2/

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle

Comment: I tested the first solution, and it works, but I might be interested in more, thanks to the docs you gave me. Thanks a lot!