# Choice Multiple = true, create new Entries

Tags: symfony, entity, symfony-forms

My Entity

```
/**
 * Set friend
 *
 * @param \Frontend\ChancesBundle\Entity\UserFriends $friend
 * @return ChanceRequest
 */
public function setFriend(\Frontend\ChancesBundle\Entity\UserFriends $friend = null)
{
    $this->friend = $friend;

    return $this;
}
```

My Action

```
$task = new ChanceRequest();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('friend', 'choice', array(
                'required' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choices' => $fb_friends,
                'multiple' => true,
                'mapped' => true
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

Because `setFriend` is expecting a scalar, I cannot validate this or save it to db. It is an array from how many friends the user want to send a message to somebody. How can I change it?

I have seen here a post:
[Symfony2 Choice : Expected argument of type "scalar", "array" given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261976/symfony2-choice-expected-argument-of-type-scalar-array-given)
but this don't work that I put an array in front of `\Frontend` or `$friend.` I guess because of the related table.

What do I have to do in Entity to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `friends` could be found in your database (for example it is a User entity), you should declare `ManyToMany` relationship for these two tables. If not, make `friend` property to be a doctrine array type. if friends is not a valid entity class, all the rest you have is to make a custom validator and datatransformer. Otherwise you have nothing left to do. All this information you can find in the official symfony and doctrine documentation.

[How to create a Custom Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

[How to use Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

[Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html)

[Working with Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html)